# The code to set placement and font size of caption/legend of line plot image in DM

Tags: dm-script

Try to get the code to set placement and font size of caption/legend of line plot image by DM scripting, as show in the attached pics, can not find them in the help files, only get LinePlotImageDisplayIsLegendShown, any suggestions? thx
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple questions, so one at a time

- The *legend section* of a lineplot can not be altered. It can only be shown or hidden. It's size and position is always automatically determined by the application.
- The *caption* font and text size can not be altered by script with the current version of GMS. You may want to file a *feature-request* for such a script command here: [Gatan issue/bug submission form](https://swbugs.gatan.com/loginsolosubmit.htm).
- The *placement* coordinates of the window in your screen-shot represents just the coordinates and size of the image window on the workspace and not any of the lineplot content. So you would set it like:

  ```
  image plot := RealImage("Plot",4,500)
  plot = sin( icol/iwidth*5*pi() )
  plot.ShowImage()

  ImageDocument doc = plot.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
  DocumentWindow win = doc.ImageDocumentGetWindow()

  number posX = 100
  number posY = 50
  win.WindowSetFramePosition( posX, posY )

  number w = 1200
  number h = 200
  win.WindowSetFrameSize( w, h )
  ```

  More commands on window placement are found here:

  [image]